# How to shrink the size of $\infty$ for subscripts

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontsize

When using `\infty` as a subscipt, the usual size is just too big for me, for example,

```
I_\infty,J_\infty,K_\infty,\dots
```

I tried `\scriptsize` or `\tiny` to shrink it, but does not work. Is there any way to do this (I prefer not to include extra package for this)?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), this will be affected by the font packages you are using and the tex engine you compile with.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for your remind. This question is just for generic environment. Next time I will give a MWE.

Comment: See also: http://martin-thoma.com/sizes-in-latex

Comment: TroyWoo: Even for a _generic_ environment you should still provide one (as illustrated in @LaRiFaRi's answer). This saves those trying to help some time and also goes a long way to clear up any confusions that often arise.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok, I see, you mean a snapshot, rather than MWE. I will do it next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different 'sizes' for fonts in math-mode are:

- `\displaystyle`
- `\textstyle`
- `\scriptstyle`
- `\scriptscriptstyle`

If you want to change their value, you could do:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{d-size}{t-size}{s-size}{ss-size}
```

In your example, I would just define a new command for your subscript:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myInfty}{{\scriptscriptstyle\infty}}

\begin{document}
\[I_\myInfty,J_\myInfty,K_\myInfty,\dots\]
\end{document}
```

[image]